# React / Electron Rendering Components Is Failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

First of all I am new to whole React and Electron thing so I am not sure if the thing I am doing is correct. I am trying to separate my components into different JSX files and import them and render them into div tags in my index page for my Electron app. However, I am a bit confused because it "partially" works. I am trying to separate my tab pages. I have one container file which looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import NavigationLeft from '../Components/Layout/Navigation.jsx';
import TabPane1 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane1.jsx';
import TabPane2 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane2.jsx';
import TabPane3 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane3.jsx';
import TabPane4 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane4.jsx';
import TabPane5 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane5.jsx';
import TabPane6 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane6.jsx';
import TabPane7 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane7.jsx';

window.onload = function(){
  ReactDOM.render(<NavigationLeft />, document.getElementById('viewNavigationLeft'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane1 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane1'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane2 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane2'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane3 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane3'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane4 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane4'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane5 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane5'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane6 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane6'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane7 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPane7'));

}
```

The content on my index.html page seems like loading fine however when it is rendering my components into the page, it is duplicating "TabPane1" only, the rest is not even there. Literally looks like they are duplicated.

My index.html page

```
<html>
<head>
...yada yada
<script>
        // install babel hooks in the renderer process
        require('babel-register');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require('./Containers/MainApp');
    </script>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="viewNavigationLeft" class="sidebar" data-color="blue" ></div>
        <div id="viewMainPanel" class="main-panel">
            <div id="viewTabPagesTest" class="tab-content">
                <div id="viewTabPane1"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane2"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane3"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane4"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane5"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane6"></div>
                <div id="viewTabPane7"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Finally, my component contents (just one of them) looks like following:

```
'use babel';

import React from 'react';

class TabPane1 extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="tab-pane" id="tabPane1">
                yada yada blah blah tab content for tabPane1
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TabPane1
```

If I populate these into divs separately as I stated above, it does populate them but it breaks the tabpage functionality - tab script expects the tab pages to be populated under the "viewTabPagesTest" div directly, rather than having another div under it.

If I do the same thing by targeting viewTabPagesTest directly, it only renders the last element, not all of the tab pages. So that's where I am lost actually.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import NavigationLeft from '../Components/Layout/Navigation.jsx';
import TabPane1 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane1.jsx';
import TabPane2 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane2.jsx';
import TabPane3 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane3.jsx';
import TabPane4 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane4.jsx';
import TabPane5 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane5.jsx';
import TabPane6 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane6.jsx';
import TabPane7 from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane7.jsx';

window.onload = function(){
  ReactDOM.render(<NavigationLeft />, document.getElementById('viewNavigationLeft'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane1 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane2 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane3 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane4 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane5 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane6 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
  ReactDOM.render(<TabPane7 />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));

}
```

What is the correct way to achieve this - to render my components into a single div at once?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to render your navigation page and then inside your navigation page, render out your tab panes.  Ideally you would only call `ReactDOM.render` once. Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import NavigationLeft from '../Components/Layout/Navigation.jsx';

window.onload = function(){
  // ideally you pick a div and render your whole application rather than bits and pieces of it. 
  ReactDOM.render(<NavigationLeft />, document.getElementById('left'));
}

<html>
<head>
...yada yada
<script>
        // install babel hooks in the renderer process
        require('babel-register');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        require('./Containers/MainApp');
    </script>

    <div class="wrapper" id="left">
    </div>

</body>
```

`NavigationLeft.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import-your-tabs from 'wherever';

export default class NavigationLeft extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="viewNavigationLeft" class="sidebar" data-color="blue" ></div>
        <div id="viewMainPanel" class="main-panel">
            <div id="viewTabPagesTest" class="tab-content">
                <TabPane1 />
                <TabPane2 />
                .
                .
                .
                <TabPane7 />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`TabPane1.jsx`

```
'use babel';

import React from 'react';

export default class TabPane1 extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return(
        <div className="tab-pane" id="tabPanel1">
            yada yada blah blah tab content for tabPane1
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying I should not separate my tab panes into files, but rather keep them in a single JSX file and render that instead?

Comment: You can separate your tab panes in to separate files if you want to, but it looks like theyre very similar and could be abstracted in to a single component that takes in props.  I'll update my post with some example code

Comment: Your code should look something like this.  ReactDOM.render is called once, and then the render functions of the child nodes are recursively called down to the last node.  I left out the abstraction of the `TabPanes`

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating yourself. That's unnecessary. Trying creating props inside the tabs and use one component called TabPane. For example by using props you would not have to have so much code that does the same thing. Try something like

```
class TabPane extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="tab-pane">
            {this.props.paneText}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then when you are going to use it somewhere else the thing you have to do is simply.

```
import TabPane from '../Components/TabPanes/TabPane.jsx';

class TabContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TabPane paneText='This my first tabPane' />
        <TabPane paneText='Second tabPane' />  
     </div>
  )
}
```

Then you you have to create an App.jsx and then put all your containers there. When you have done this you can simply write ;

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('viewTabPagesTest'));
```

It would be good to check the [Hierarchies in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).